# php xpath iterating through inner nodes, get values based on specific attributes

Tags: php, xpath, attributes

I have an XML document in following structure.

```
<rows pos="0" rec_count="200">
    <row id="109">
        <cell style="" fieldName="pid">104</cell>
        <cell style="" fieldName="title">Mr.</cell>
        <cell style="" fieldName="name">Vladimir</cell>
        <cell style="" fieldName="projectcode">879</cell>
        <cell style="" fieldName="clientstatus">1000000000</cell>
    </row>
    <row id="111">
        <cell style="" fieldName="pid">105</cell>
        <cell style="" fieldName="title">Mr.</cell>
        <cell style="" fieldName="name">Barak</cell>
        <cell style="" fieldName="projectcode">789/cell>
        <cell style="" fieldName="clientstatus">1000000000</cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

Now I need to get value of each row, to an array, which each row element is an associative array where fieldName of above becomes key, element value is node value.

How can I do accomplish this with XPath?

I tried several methods; none worked for me yet.

Thanks @JeffreyBosboom , @Makyen for your reply.

The most successfull I came is as follows.

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//row') as $node) {
    foreach($node->cell as $cell) { 
        var_dump((string)$cell[0]);
    }
}
```

With it I can get the node value. But I need to get the fieldName attribute extracted in each iteration

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you show us what you tried and explain why those attempts didn't do what you want.

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `(string) $cell` is the value of the *cell* element and `(string) $cell['fieldName']` of the *fieldName* attribute of it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$arr = array();
$s = simplexml_load_string($xml);

//First we search all the <cell> nodes within <row> nodes 
foreach($s->xpath("//row/cell") as $node)
{
    //For all found nodes we retrieve its ID from ancestor (<row>) 
    //attribute named id
    $id = $node->xpath("../@id");
    $id = (int)$id[0];
    if(!isset($arr[$id]))
    {
        $arr[$id] = array();
    }

    //Then we iterate through all attributes of found <cell> nodes
    //to find the attribute named fieldName
    foreach($node->attributes() as $key=>$att)
    {
        if($key=='fieldName')
        {
            $arr[$id][(string)$att] = (string)$node;
        }

    }   
}

//In $arr array there will be desired output
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

?

Comment: Please explain your code a bit more so other people can benefit from it!